# Why the am/pm is not showing on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I have a strange issue after upgrading to Mavericks from Mountain Lion. The am/pm does not show on the menu bar always. Sometime it shows and sometime not. What could be the reason ? I am running 10.9.1 now.

[image: Menu bar]

[image]

Comment: I see it correctly (I don't normally use it but activating it reveals no issues, apparently). Have you tried rebooting? If you have just upgraded, it might help.

Comment: Go to **Date & Time** in **System Preferences** and see whether AM/PM is on. Attach the screenshot that panel in the question too.

Comment: @sayzlim - If you read my question carefully, I have written that, it shows sometime and sometime not. It has been an issue since I have upgraded in Oct/Nov '13.

Comment: It looks like you're not the only one:  https://discussions.apple.com/message/23632584#23632584  If it's a deep Mavericks bug, you might need to wait for a fix from Apple.